# Jpa OneToMany Relation not woriking

Tags: exception, jpa, cascade, check-constraints

I have an issue trying to persist an Entity with a @OneToMany Relatioship and I don't get it solved. (Sorry, I'm not an english native speaker).

These are the Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@lombok.ToString
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "id" })
public class Parent extends EntityBase<Long> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PARENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PARENT_SEQ", sequenceName = "PARENT_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID") })
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

The Child Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@lombok.ToString
@lombok.EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false, of = { "id" })
public class Child extends EntityBase<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CHILD_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CHILD_SEQ", sequenceName = "CHILD_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Long id;
}
```

The Exception I get is:

```
integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10153 table: CHILD column: PARENT_ID
```

Since Cascade is set to all, I though, the chidren would be persisted and that this occures after Parent has been persisted. That way the PARENT_ID already exists and will be set as the foreign key in the children rows.

The tables look like this:

```
PARENT
PARENT_ID   NUMBER(30,0)    No  

CHILD
CHILD_ID    NUMBER(30,0)    No          
PARENT_ID   NUMBER(30,0)    No
```

Has anybody an Idea what I'm possibly doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved. I forgot to add the other side of the relationship :-/. It means, child.setParent(parent). Sorry for the time waste....